# WPF login form with effect

Tags: wpf

I am WPF beginner. Recently I watch few WPF related videos from youtube.com. I saw those developer develop very beautiful login form with effect but they did not show how they developed.

Please visit the link to see the behavior of applications.

1) [Login form with some effect](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVlSj0yr3rg) - here you can see nice login form appearance effect. So any expert WPF developer, please give me the concept how I can develop the same login form with the same effect.

2) [Semi transparent login form with multi color background](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWO89WxVRmk) -  please tell me how to design that kind of window with semi transparent effect with multi color background.

3) [Sliding login form](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dT1-pyhz9uo) - please tell me how to design that kind of sliding login form effect.

Please discuss all in detail and if possible then please give me the code snippet which enable me to design that kind window with effect. I am new in WPF. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, I've seen and responded to a few of your WPF posts here today. Might I recommend that you check out the Development For Beginners section of MSDN to start learning some of what you'd like to learn? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/dd435692.aspx

Comment: Hi, your questions are to wide and do not solve any problem. That why i think it will be really hard to get some rational answer on this site. I think that Brian Driscoll advice is the best shot for you to master the WPF and other staff that are related. Sometimes the development of software can be compared with art. It is hard to explain thing that someone created. That was a concept of person, the realization is second had thing. So try to learn the basic, and then create own sophisticated solution. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is done by using Microsoft Expression Blend. This latter allows you to create animations for your controlls, managing there opacity (for the transparency); You can find loads of tutorials about Blend on youtube.

Hopefully this will help.